# Wordpress 'Edit category' is appearing instead of 'Edit Post'

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Wordpress is providing a new feature where if you are logged in you can easily get an admin bar on the top while browsing the site. This is very helpful if you want to edit any particular post/page.

The problem is my team is building a theme in WP version 3.1.1 and this feature was working perfectly until recent. Right now there is always an 'Edit Category' option appears regardless of posts/pages/category I'm browsing. It supposed to be 'Edit Post' or 'Edit Page' if I'm in a post or page. And clicking 'Edit Category' always leads to a particular category called 'Press' irrespective of the category I'm browsing. We have worked on function.php a lot and modified it such so it renders posts and categories with different templates  based on the category. It was fine with this logic implemented as we could easily edit posts pages from top admin. But for some reason its not working now!

Any help will be appreciated ! Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Do you have a custom loop that queries posts from the `press` category? Maybe a widget in a sidebar?

Comment: @Jan Fabry: yes there was a query in the footer without calling wp_reset_query(). After following what @Alex said below its now working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After every custom loop you're having, make sure to use `wp_reset_query()`

Comment: You are right! I missed it in a footer query :) Now working perfectly! Thnx a lot !